# How to get the Center value of a column in the Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of values below for which I need to use a formula to get the middle number. I do not want the values in decimals (not the median, but just the middle number)

[image]

The answer must be an Exact Middle value , i. e 3353

Comment: How is the median different from the middle number? And what would you do if there were an even count of numbers, such as {1, 2, 7, 10}? Pick 2? Pick 7? Pick 4.5 (= (2 + 7) / 2) ?

Comment: Are there always an odd number of rows?

Comment: You say you need to use a formula but you tagged the question with vba and excel-vba.  So are you ok without using a formula?

Comment: Ok No Problem Without using the Formula Also

Comment: what is the answer if you have an even number of rows?

Comment: @TomSharpe We have add and Even rows Both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that in theory, you're after a cell reference - not a value - so:

If the range of cells is C1:C5 you want to return what's in C3, regardless of the values?

If so then try this:

**=INDEX(A1:A7,ROUNDUP(COUNT(A1:A7)/2,0))**

Answer (score 1):

Excel has the function already written. If these are in column A, I'd recommend `=MEDIAN(A:A)`.

If there are an even count of rows, it will give you the average between the rows just around the middle.

Comment: I tried median with your 7 numbers and got 3353. I knocked off the highest number (that is, 6 numbers from 3350 to 3356) and got 3352.5.